# How can I arrange it so that I can use Greek characters directly in my LaTeX sources?

Tags: xetex, unicode, greek

Support for non-ASCII characters has come a long way since the 1980s, and today we are accustomed, as users of computing devices, to be able to insert arbitrary Unicode characters via differing keyboard layouts, and for them to be recognized and rendered reasonably.

Can I do that with, say, XeLaTeX?

Naively, if I just write:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
A greek letter: φ ... do you see it?

A greek letter in math mode: $φ$ ... do you see it?
\end{document}
```

and pass this through XeLaTeX (version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995, in TeX Live 2023) - nothing is rendered for either of the φ characters:

[image]

... and I get:

```
Missing character: There is no φ (U+03C6) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
```

Note: I would rather avoid explicitly setting a font, but if that's the only way to achieve what I want - please suggest settings which result in something as close as possible to the default font (Computer Modern, right?) and to $\phi$ in math mode.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `minimal` class for examples, it is too minimal

Comment: You can use the command line tool `albatross` to check which of your fonts has these letters and use this font via `fontspec`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: "shouldn't use minimal" - Ok, but - does that have bearing on my question?

Comment: No, that was just a general comment to keep in mind for all your future questions.

Comment: @campa: I know that from 15 years ago. Question is, what do I do about it these days?

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700246/82917

Comment: @campa: I'm willing to accept that as a dupe, if you think it is.

Answer (score 3):

As you are already using an unicode aware engine, you can use `fontspec` and `unicode-math` to select text and math fonts which contain these symbols.

For example:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif Roman}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{LatinModernMath-Regular}

\begin{document}
A greek letter: φ ... do you see it?

A greek letter in math mode: $φ$ ... do you see it?
\end{document}
```

[image]

To find out which of your text fonts contain a `φ`, you can use the command line tool albatross: `albatross φ`

Comment: ... but I don't want to change the font ...

Comment: ... then choose a font which looks like computer modern

Comment: @einpoklum you do want to change the font as the whole issue is that you are using latin modern and latin modern has no Greek characters in the text fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I realize that, but - I want to do something very naive: Make Greek work without chaning other things. I don't want to be told that I need to typeset my document in a completely different font so as to be able to use Greek. that was why I gave that whole spiel about our modern era etc.

Comment: @einpoklum sure but a font is a human creation: someone has to sit down and draw all those characters. Latin Modern does not have Greek (there is a clue in the name) so saying you want it to have Greek does not make it happen. There are thousands of fonts with Greek, you can use any one of them, but you can't use latin modern. Fonts such as New Computer Modern, or Computer Modern Unicode are similarly derived from Computer Modern so similar design, and do have Greek, but basically the answer is you have to change the font to something.

Comment: "Latin Modern does not have Greek (there is a clue in the name)" <- but the naive user does not choose Latin modern. They just enter a simple document with both Latin and Greek characters.

Comment: @einpoklum Latin Modern is the default font of Unicode engines (i.e., XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX). If it is so limited, is it even a good choice as the default font? Maybe not, but I must say LaTeX has progressed a lot. In TeX, PDFTeX and PDFLaTeX Unicode isn't even a valid input. The compilation fails if non-ASCII characters are spotted. Slowly and steadily we are moving towards inclusive typesetting. The New Computer Modern project is swiftly moving towards a wide coverage of Unicode with the default design. Currently even naive users have to comply with this, but I am hoping this changes soon.